How to directly cast array of Objects to array of Integer without modifications
I have an Objects array filled up with Strings:
Object[] array = new Object[count];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = String.valueOf(i);
}

Then I refill it with Integers:
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
}

I want to return an object of type Integer[]. When I do:
return (Integer[]) array;

or
return Integer[].class.cast(array);

I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Integer; ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [Ljava.lang.Integer; are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap').
I don't want to use streams, copying array or any other modifications or transformations. Just direct casting, maybe even via reflection.
Are there any options?

Arrays know their component type at run-time. You can't cast an Object[] to an Integer[] just like you can't cast an Object (i.e., new Object()) to an Integer. You'll have to create a new array with the desired component type and then copy the objects over. Or keep the original object array and cast each element to integer when you iterate (not the safest option).

It's not an array, but you can do this with a generic list and unchecked casting using a wildcard list: List<?>. You can even cast it when it contains objects of different types, it'll throw a ClassCastException when you try to access them as the generic type.
ArrayList<Object> arr = new ArrayList<Object>();
arr.add(1);
arr.add("xyz");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
ArrayList<Integer> casted = (ArrayList<Integer>) (ArrayList<?>) arr;

System.out.println(casted.get(0)); // Prints 1
System.out.println(casted.get(1)); // Prints "xyz"
        
Integer first = casted.get(0); // Works!
// Integer second = casted.get(1); // Throws ClassCastException at runtime
// String secondStr = casted.get(1); // Doesn't compile, 'incompatible types'
String secondStrGood = (String) (Object) casted.get(1); // Works!

This is because ArrayLists just use an Object[] array instead of a generic T[] array, and casts on get (sort of...)

If you try to be sneaky and retrieve the internal array backing an ArrayList through reflection, no dice there. It's just a normal Object[] array as previously mentioned, so you get the same casting issue.
Field privateField = casted.getClass().getDeclaredField("elementData"); 
privateField.setAccessible(true); 

// java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
Integer[] array = (Integer[]) privateField.get(casted); 


If you try to be even sneakier and try this trick with a generic class instead of a List<?>, it still doesn't work.
public class Test<T> {
    public T[] array;
}
    
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Object[] objArray = new Object[] {1, "string"};

    Test<Object> test = new Test<Object>();
    test.array = objArray;
        
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Test<Integer> testInteger = (Test<Integer>) (Test<?>) test;

    // java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    Integer[] intArray = testInteger.array;
}


TL;DR: best you can do is with Collections

Actually it's the best answer. Double casting is what I needed

@Max If you use this unchecked cast approach, make sure nothing keeps a reference to the list as a List<Object> after you publish the list as a List<Integer>. Referencing the same list with conflicting generic parameterizations can lead to hard-to-narrow-down ClassCastExceptions.

What you do with your custom Test<T> class, can be done with existing List implementations either, List<Integer> list = (List)Arrays.asList(objArray);

@Holger did you mean can't be done? I get a ClassCastException when trying to cast an Arrays.asList array to a different T type

You can cast the List instance the same way as the Test instance and you can’t cast the array in either case. online demo

@Holger ah, explicitly casting to (List<Integer>) throws, but not specifying the type (List) doesn't throw? Weird.

List is a raw type. Using raw types destroys the type safety of Generics (and may generate a compiler warning on its own). Effectively, (List) works like a short-hand for (List<Integer>) (List<?>) in this case.

The fact that an Object[] is filled with instances of Integer does not make it an Integer[]. Here's an easy way to think about it - even if it is filled with Integers right now, there's nothing preventing you from doing array[0] = "I am not an Integer".
In short, such a cast will not be possible. The only way to achieve this is to copy the contents of this array to an actual Integer[], e.g., by using streams:
Integer[] integerArray = Arrays.stream(array).toArray(Integer[]::new);

Alternatively, you could just cast any element retrieved from the array before using it:
for (Object o : array) {
    Integer i = (Integer) o;
    // Use i for something
}


Once all are of same type you could make a safe copy as an array of the right format using Arrays.copy.
Examples:
Integer[] intArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, Integer[].class);
// or
String[] strArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length, String[].class);

These throw java.lang.ArrayStoreException if any element is not of the correct type.

The OP explicitly specified they do not want the array to be copied.  (That's impossible, but your answer should say that instead.)

@LouisWasserman it was already stated by Mureinik and so I felt not worth copying.

Only way is to create new array.
For example:
Arrays.copyOf(new Object[1], 1, Integer.class);

